# Decode bytes starting with \x02 and ending with \x03 control character

Tags: python, decode

I'm trying to decode a byte string as follows:

```py
b'\x02"Name"\x03'
```

The start text control character is `\x02` and stop text is `\x03`.
I want to decode `"Name"` from the byte string in Python.

`b'\x02"Name"\x03'.decode()` doesn't work, it just returns the string `'\x02"Name"\x03'`.

I don't want to resort to doing regex if at all possible.  I seem to think this is doable with a function in Python but I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: The use of `\x02` and `\x03` isn't a matter of character encoding. It's just some custom binary format that you'll need to parse yourself.

Comment: `text[text.index('\x02')+1:text.index('\x03')]` would do that, although it would fail if those control characters were missing, or there was more than one of each.

Comment: `src = b'\x02"Name"\x03' ; start_delim = b'\x02' ; end_delim = b'\x03' ; result =  src[src.index(start_delim) + len(start_delim): src.index(end_delim)].decode()`

Comment: `b'\x02"Name"\x03'.decode().strip('\x02\x03')`

Comment: `decode()` (often used ed with a parameter like `encoding=‘utf-8’`) converts binary bytes into Python’s unicode strings. Not clear what you’re expecting, but it won’t remove \x02 and \x03 like you seem to think it might.

Comment: Thanks to the responders, it gave me more insight.
I found a simple way by using slicing:
b'\x02"Name"\x03'[1:-1].decode()

Comment: It can also be sliced after decode():
b'\x02"Name"\x03'.decode()[1:-1]